# How to get magit to ignore branches associated with closed pull requests?

Tags: magit

I'm struggling to find a good workflow for managing pull requests from magit.  (I am approving pull requests, not generating them.)  At the moment I am using `m p` to preview a pull request and `m m` to merge it, but my autocompletion is cluttered with obsolete pull-request branches like `github/pull/112`.  How can I get magit to ignore these closed requests?

I would be happy enough to switch to some other workflow, but I have had no luck finding anything.  (I did find `magit-gh-pulls`, which is on MELPA if marked "obsolete," but I cannot get it to configure properly with our Github Enterprise instance, and all I learned from its messages is that it is trying to contact `api.github.com`.)

Comment: "pull-request branches like `github/pull/112`" - branches are not pull-requests. I guess you just need to delete those branches?

Comment: OK, clearly I don't know what's going on.  Maybe I should ask a different question: how should I be handling pull requests within magit?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm struggling to find a good workflow for managing pull requests from magit.

It sounds like you're just missing the "delete after merging" step.  The [manual entry for `magit-branch-pull-request`](https://magit.vc/manual/2.13.0/magit/The-Branch-Popup.html#index-magit_002dbranch_002dpull_002drequest) describes the intended flow:

> - <kbd>b Y</kbd> (`magit-branch-pull-request`)
>
>   This command creates and configures a new branch from a Github
>     pull-request, creating and configuring a new remote if necessary.
>
>   [...]
>
>   When you later delete the local pull-request branch, then you are
>     offered to also delete the corresponding remote, provided it is not
>     the upstream remote and that the tracking branch that corresponds to
>     the deleted branch is the only remaining tracked branch. [...]

Pull-request branches are normal branches, so they can be deleted with <kbd>b k</kbd> ([`magit-branch-delete`](https://magit.vc/manual/2.13.0/magit/The-Branch-Popup.html#index-magit_002dbranch_002ddelete)) as usual.